# Animating in Real time problem

Tags: animation

I was trying to replicate the effect here in this video :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoSRMxMDYsk

However, the problem is that if I try to animate it like in the video in real time, it just starts glitching out like crazy. But it doesn't in the video.

When I animate it once with just location is fine. But if I do another pass with rotation only, the cube will spasm out and not rotate correctly as the original location animation plays out

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: No, if you dont tell us more info this is impossible.

Comment: It's simple. When i animate it once with just location is fine. But if I do another pass with rotation, the cube will spasm out and not rotate as the original location animation plays out.

Comment: i had a similar problem and had to use keying sets to limit what you animate in each pass